# How to run NativeScript app on android studio?

Tags: javascript, android-studio, nativescript

please does anyone have an idea on how to run NativeScript app on android studio?
If so, show me the steps to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio is meant for development using stock Android stack(Java, gradle, etc).

NativeScript is based on JavaScript and you would be much better off using an IDE that supports JS specifically - Visual Studio Code, Sublime Text, Atom, etc. If you prefer IntelliJ you can try [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/).

Comment: While you are correct that the user will be better off using a text editor as their IDE, that does not mean that the Android Project cannot be opened and ran in Android Studio.

Comment: While its possible...its not worth the effort.

Comment: It's as simple as opening a directory. Voila, there's your project, you can manipulate it most ways that you can a regular Android project, save for editing the javascript files, as it's not worth the effort as you stated. Other than that, it's great for taking advantage of the Android Studio tooling.